# Can't write to Firebase database from Auth success listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth (email and password), and a Firebase database.
I am trying to write to the database upon successful registration.
I am using the simple database writing query, as provided by the Firebase assistant:

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

It does work if I write it simply under the `onCreate` method of the activity, but when I write it inside the Auth success listener, the account does register, but the message is not written to the database:

```
// [START sign_in_with_email]
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    // Write a message to the database
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
                    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");

                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
          //rest of code 
}
```

Comment: can you show the log

Comment: If you are using the following line of code `Log.d(TAG, user.getUid());` inside the `onComplete()` method, is it printed in the logcat? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, nope it does not get printed in the logcat

Comment: @Lucem, what part of the log? It's very long

Comment: @Fireio So it means that the authentication process does not complete, right? Have you tried to add the else part of your if statement and use `task.getException().getMessage()` to see if something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are certain steps to Use firebase database in android.

Enable the Email id and password Authentication in Firebase Console

Register the Email and Password From Code

with the help of

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email, txt_password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        String UserId = firebaseUser.getUid();
```

}

Use Hashmap to set Value.

**And Sign In using this code**

```
    private void login(String txt_email, String txt_password) {
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email,txt_password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this,MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        String error = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage();
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       // Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

If u have further doubt. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your firebase rules allow write when you are not authenticated

Step 1: Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[projectname]/database/[projectname]/rules

Step 2: Allow access to the database by pasting the following code

```
{

"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Step 3: Publish

The code makes your database public, its not advisable to leave it so and you should secure it once you are done testing and development.